# Anybody help me to understand the execution of queries in TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql

```
 select * from events where detector='PhotoWatcher' 
   AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,(select event_occured from events where description 
     LIKE '%Lat:18%' OR '%Lng:73%' LIMIT 1), 
   (select event_occured from events where detector='PhotoWatcher' LIMIT 1))>0;
```

**Are they executing as nested "for" loops? OR 1st row of result1 with 1st row of result2**

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and MySQL will tell you. Check the [`EXPLAIN` Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) to find out how to improve its running time.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have the following nested DO loops:

```
 DO
   statements-1
   DO
      statement-2
   END DO
   statement-3
END DO
```

Each iteration of the outer DO starts with statements-1. When the control reaches the inner DO, statements-2 is executed until some condition of the inner DO brings the control out of it. Then, statements-3 is executed and this completes one iteration. Any EXIT in the inner DO brings the control out of the inner DO to the first statement in statement-3.

The following are a few simple examples:

In the following nested loops, the outer one has i running from 1 to 9 with step size 1. For each iteration, say the i-th one, the inner loop iterates 9 times with values of j being 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. Therefore, with i fixed, the WRITE is executed 9 times and the output consists of i*1, i*2, i*3, ..., i*9.

```
INTEGER :: i, j

DO i = 1, 9
   DO j = 1, 9
     WRITE(*,*)  i*j
   END DO
END DO
```

Once this is done, the value of i is advanced to the next one, and the inner loop will iterate 9 times again displaying the product of the new i and 1, 2, 3,4 ..., 9.

The net effect is a multiplication table. For i=1, the value if 1*1, 1*2, 1*3, ..., 1*9 are displayed; for i=2, the displayed values are 2*1, 2*2, 2*3, ..., 2*9; ...; for i=9, the displayed values are 9*1, 9*2, 9*3, ..., 9*9.

The following shows a nested DO-loop. The outer one lets u run from 2 to 5. For each u, the inner DO lets v runs from 1 to u-1. Therefore, when u is 2, the values for v is from 1 to 1. When u is 3, the values for v are 1 and 2. When u is 4, the values for v are 1, 2, and 3. Finally, when u is 5, the values for v are 1, 2, 3 and 4.

```
INTEGER :: u, v
INTEGER :: a, b, c

DO u = 2, 5
   DO v = 1, u-1
      a = 2*u*v
      b = u*u - v*v
      c = u*u + v*v
      WRITE(*,*)  a, b, c
   END DO
END DO
```

The above discussion can be summarized in the following table:

```
u   Values for v
2   1   


3   1   2   

4   1   2   3   
5   1   2   3   4
```

For each pair of u and v, the inner loop computes a, b and c. Thus, it will generate the following result (please verify it):

```
u   v   a   b   c
2   1   4   3   5
3   1   6   8   10
2   12  5   13
4   1   8   15  17
2   16  12  20
3   24  7   25
5   1   10  24  26
2   20  21  29
3   30  16  34
4   40  9   41
```

It is obvious that the inner DO-loop computes the sum of all integers in the range of 1 and i (i.e., Sum is equal to 1+2+3+...+i). Since i runs from 1 to 10, the following loop computes ten sums: 1, 1+2, 1+2+3, 1+2+3+4, ...., 1+2+3+...+9, and 1+2+3+...+9+10.

```
INTEGER :: i, j, Sum

DO i = 1, 10
   Sum = 0
   DO j = 1, i
      Sum = Sum + j
   END DO
   WRITE(*,*)  Sum
END DO
```

The program below uses Newton's method for computing the square root of a positive number. In fact, it computes the square roots of the numbers 0.1, 0.1, ..., 0.9 and 1.0.

```
REAL :: Start = 0.1, End = 1.0, Step = 0.1
REAL :: X, NewX, Value

Value = Start
DO
   IF (Value > End)  EXIT
   X = Value
   DO
      NewX = 0.5*(X + Value/X)
      IF (ABS(X - NewX) < 0.00001)  EXIT
      X = NewX
   EBD DO
   WRITE(*,*)  'The square root of ', Value, ' is ', NewX
   Value = Value + Step
END DO
```

Newton's method is taken directly from the programming example, where X is the current guess, NewX is the new guess, and Value is the number for square root computation. The EXIT statement brings the execution of the inner DO to the WRITE statement.

If the inner loop is removed, we have the outer loop as follows:

```
REAL :: Start = 0.1, End = 1.0, Step = 0.1
REAL :: X, NewX, Value

Value = Start
DO
   IF (Value > End)  EXIT
!
! the inner loop computes the result in NewX
!
   WRITE(*,*)  'The square root of ', Value, ' is ', NewX
   Value = Value + Step`enter code here`
END DO
```

It is clear that the value of Value starts with 0.1 and have a step size 0.1 until 1.0. Thus, the values of Value are 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 0.9 and 1.0. For each value of Value, the inner loop computes the square root of Value. The EXIT statement in the outer loop brings the control out of the outer loop.